# Get bounds of a node relative to another node/pane javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a `TextArea` which is in a `ScrollPane` where the `ScrollPane` can be found by invoking `getParent()` five times on the `TextArea`. Is there a way for me to find the coordinates of the `TextArea` relative to the `ScrollPane`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Bounds bounds = 
    scrollPane.sceneToLocal(textArea.localToScene(textArea.getBoundsInLocal()));
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaBoundsInScrollPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

        VBox scrollPaneContent = new VBox(5);
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        scrollPaneContent.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        scrollPaneContent.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        scrollPaneContent.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(200, 80, Color.CORAL));
        scrollPaneContent.getChildren().add(textArea);
        scrollPaneContent.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(200, 120, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE));

        scrollPane.setContent(scrollPaneContent);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
        root.setTop(new TextField());
        root.setBottom(new TextField());

        ChangeListener<Object> boundsChangeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Bounds bounds = scrollPane.sceneToLocal(textArea.localToScene(textArea.getBoundsInLocal()));
            System.out.printf("[%.1f, %.1f], %.1f x %.1f %n", bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
        };

        textArea.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(boundsChangeListener);
        textArea.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(boundsChangeListener);
        scrollPane.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(boundsChangeListener);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this find the bounds of the textArea? It doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Yes, it will give the bounds of the text area in the coordinate system of the scroll pane.